# regular expression OR two and more conditions?

Tags: python, regex

I had 3 mostly the same regular expression

```
re_pattern = re.compile(r'[\w\.-]+ \(at\) +[\w\.-]+')
re_pattern = re.compile(r'[\w\.-]+\ at\ +[\w\.-]+')
re_pattern = re.compile(r'[\w\.-]+\(at\)+[\w\.-]+')
```

How i can combine it to one?
like

```
re_pattern = re.compile(r'[\w\.-]+\(at\)|\ at\ | \(at\) +[\w\.-]+')
```

I tried so, but not working

Comment: **What should be the match**

Comment: FYI: dot doesn't need to be escaped in character class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're permutating the same segment. You're expecting either space, parantheses or nothing before & after 'at'... so you can just put them in brackets and use `*`:

```
re_pattern = re.compile(r'[\w.\-]+[(\s]*at[)\s]*[\w.\-]+')
```

Comment: Accidentally left an excess `+` there, try again

Comment: Also for these topic   re_pattern = re.compile(r'[\w.\-]+[[(\s]*at[])\s]+[\w\.-]+', re.IGNORECASE)  is it possible to make "at" or "@"

Comment: What's with the multiple brackets there? You can just wrap `at` with parentheses and use `|` like this: `(at|@)`

Comment: I tried before re_pattern = re.compile(r'[\w.\-]+[[(\s]*(at|@)[])\s]*[\w.\-]+', re.IGNORECASE)
but got incorrect results

Comment: Also in re_pattern = re.compile(r'[\w.\-]+[(\s]*at[)\s]*[\w.\-]+') how to make just one space from word, for example   gora at gmail.com is ok, but gora      at    gmail.com    is wrong?